# Pandas - Vectorize Series method to strip 'exact' substring from the right

Tags: python, pandas

I need to left strip the prefix of units like below:

**Series**

```
units = pd.Series(['msec','mg','ml','mmol', 'mdmg'])
```

**Result:**

```
clean_units = pd.Series(['sec','g','l','mol','dmg'])
```

I tried using `units.str.lstrip('m')` but this does not work with 'mmol', as it strips both 'm's. 
I also tried `units.str.replace(r'^m.*$','')` but it replaces the whole word 'mmol' with empty string.

How do I strip off a 'exact' substring found in the left in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` with regex `^m{1}`, which replaces the first `m` only one time:

```
units.str.replace('^m{1}', '', regex=True)

0    sec
1      g
2      l
3    mol
dtype: object
```

**Or** simply cut the first letter, but its less safe and general:

```
units.str[1:]

0    sec
1      g
2      l
3    mol
dtype: object
```